# One-parameter group of nonvanishing vector field

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, gr.group-theory, riemannian-geometry

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold( if necessary one can assume it is closed), $V$ be a non-vanishing vector field of $TM$.

**Q**: Under what condition, we can say that $\overline{\exp(tV)}$, i.e. the closure of the one-parameter group in $Diff(M)$, is compact?

Is there paper or research to show such a thing?

Comment: I suspect that the keyword to search for is "almost periodic": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_periodic_function#Uniform_or_Bohr_or_Bochner_almost_periodic_functions (see the definition of Bochner)

Comment: This happens if an only if there exists a Riemannian metric on $M$ invariant under $V$.